# Passing vectors by address in c++

Tags: c++

When I pass vector to a function by address (vector &A) ,will I be able to use all the stl functions like lower_bound ,upper_bound on A . If yes , how to use them ?

Comment: `vector &A` is passing by reference, not by address, usage of standard functions is absolutely the same as with ordinary variable

Comment: I feel that this is a dup. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Yes, and you use them [as normal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). They're all documented - read the docs, and ask another question if you try something and encounter a problem you can't figure out.

Answer (score -1):

You're passing a reference, not "by address".

Within the function, the name `A` refers to the vector, just like its original name did.

You can do everything with it, like normal.

Try it and see.